# Sinatra, Kaminari pagination problems with SEQUEL and postgres

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel, kaminari

I am attempting to page a dataset with [kaminari](http://rubygems.org/gems/kaminari) on Sinatra.

In my Gemfile I have

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'
gem 'kaminari', :require => 'kaminari/sinatra'
```

The Ruby code is:

```
dataset = DB[:candidates] 
get '/candidate' do

     @items = dataset.order(:id).page(params[:page]).per(5)
     erb :candidate
end
```

and the error message is:

```
NoMethodError at /candidate
undefined method `page' for #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset:0x94a6808>

    file: app.rb
    location: block in <main>
    line: 25
```

I am stuck. I have also tried [will_paginate](http://rubygems.org/gems/will_paginate) with similar frustration and failure.

Is the query correct? I have also tried:

```
@items = dataset.order("id").page(:page=>params[:page]).per(5)
```

which produces the same error.

Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone else comes across this question, you can get pagination working in Sequel as follows without any additional gems:

Enable the extension:

```
DB.extension(:pagination)
```

Use the pagination extension (as per the question example):

```
page = Integer(params[:page]) rescue 1
@items = dataset.order(:id).paginate(page, 5)
```

Then its up to your view logic to render page links.

Answer (score 2):

The [README for Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#supported-versions) doesn't list Sequel as one of the supported ORMs.

You either need to use the [Sequel pagination plugin](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pagination_rb.html) or [follow this gist to make your own Sequel extension](https://gist.github.com/citrus/1602209).

Comment: Thank you. In any case, we (you and I ) are working on solving this with will_paginate.